# How to develop a particular solution for inhomogeneous ODE using an Ansatz method and variation of parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have been looking on wolfram reference and here regarding a method to develop solutions for an ODE based on forming an Ansatz and use Mathematica to find the coefficients.

I take the example.

$y''+4y=x^3$

I want to find the unknown coefficients of the Ansatz. We know the ansatz for $y_p$ is $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$.

So I compute the following:

```
VL1[y_] := D[y, x, x] + 4 y
yp = A1 + B1*x + C1*x^2 + D1*x^3 (*Ansatz*)
VL1[yp1]
VL1[yp] == x^3 /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 3}, {x -> 0}}
sol = Solve[%, {A1, B1, C1, D1}]
yp /. sol
```

This works well and give the particular solution

$y_p=-\frac{3x}{8} + \frac{x^3}{4}$

However, when I want to develop this into the variation of parameters method for the example:

$y''+4y'-8y=\cos x$

I am stuck. The problem is that the Ansatz is no longer containing variables and coefficients, but unknown functions. The ansatz for this is $y_p=u\cos x+v\sin x$, where $u$ and $v$ are the unknown functions to be found.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You do not use Anstaz with variation of parameters method. Just apply the formula to find $u$ and $v$. There was a question similar to this at [This finds the particular solution using variation of parameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159382/using-the-method-of-undetermined-coefficients) may be you could use that function and see if it works? To use variation of parameters you need to first find the basis solutions for the homogeneous solution.

Comment: I saw this contribution already, and it is very special and good, your work is excellent. However, I was looking for something simpler, more towards this line of computing as you see here. Is that possible you think?

Comment: I think applying these formulas is the most simple way to use variation of parameters. Here is screen shot of the formulas. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6GQm.png)  They are derived using reduction of order method. But you do not need to know that. I just would memorize them just like memorizing the quadratic formula.

Comment: Yes, these are the solutions to the variation of parameter method. But how do I plug them in the code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how do I plug them in the code above?

I do not know how to explain this in words in comment section other than by showing it.  The $y_p$ is found using variation of parameters by applying the formulas (screen shot from [math.lamar.edu](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx)

[image]

The above is implemented in [Using the method of undetermined coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159382/using-the-method-of-undetermined-coefficients)

Here is how to use the function above

```
(*returns homogeneous and particular solutioins*)
hAndp[odeH_, rhs_, y_, x_] := 
 Module[{wronskian, u1, u2, solH, y1, y2, leadingC},
  leadingC = Cases[odeH, c_ y''[x] :> c];
  leadingC = If[leadingC === {}, 1, First@leadingC];
  solH = (y[x] /. First@DSolve[odeH == 0, y[x], x]);
  {y1, y2} = solH /. C[1] y1_ + C[2] y2_ :> {y1, y2};(*basis solutions*)
  wronskian = Det[{{y1, y2}, {D[y1, x], D[y2, x]}}];
  u1 = -Integrate[y2 rhs/(leadingC*wronskian), x];
  u2 = Integrate[y1 rhs/(leadingC*wronskian), x];
  {solH, Simplify[y1 u1 + y2 u2]}
  ]
```

And now call it as follows

```
odeH = y''[x] + 4*y[x]
rhs = x^3;
{yh, yp} = hAndp[odeH, rhs, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence

```
sol = yh + yp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
 DSolve[odeH == rhs, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]